# Entity Framework 6.x Code First from Database, add column attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to replace NHibernate from a project that used CodeSmith Generator,

I want to use Entity Framework 6.x or EF Core   Code First from Database

This is what is generated

is there a way to generate it with the column name for every property, or have the property name generated with out the _ in it? something like this,

```
[Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Column("TRACKING_NUMBER")]
            public string TRACKING_NUMBER { get; set; }


            Column("START_DATE",TypeName = "date")]
            public DateTime START_DATE { get; set; }

or

 [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Column("TRACKING_NUMBER")]
            public string TRACKINGNUMBER { get; set; }


            Column("START_DATE",TypeName = "date")]
            public DateTime STARTDATE { get; set; }
```

Comment: There are [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/codegen/) available.

Comment: Do we know if the T4 Template for EF 6 Code First from Database is available for modification?

Comment: Yes: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/